# Using glob for looping through files in a folder causes an error when the folder is empty

Tags: bash, shell, sh, glob

Using glob for looping through files in a folder causes an error **when the folder is empty**. When it is empty, I would expect the loop not to occur (0 elements), but it does enter the loop and forwards the "unresolved glob string", which is very surprising (at least for me).

The `sh` file:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e 
set -x 
update_jar_version_in_all_deployment_files() {

  for file in "deployment/"*".json"; do
    echo "parsing file $file"
    tmp=$(mktemp)
    jq --arg jar "$JAR" '.libraries[].jar=$jar' "$file" > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$file"
  done
 
 # why does it reach the echo and print foo?
 echo foo
 exit
}
```

And get this printed:

```
+ for file in 'deployment/*.json'
+ echo 'parsing file deployment/*.json'
parsing file deployment/*.json
++ mktemp
+ tmp=/var/folders/ks/y7ym1ylx6qjf0k7_kjz2z9hc0000gn/T/tmp.126PU72C
+ jq --arg jar my-jar.jar '.libraries[].jar=$jar' 'deployment/*.json'
jq: error: Could not open file deployment/*.json: No such file or directory
+ echo foo
foo
+ exit
```

Why is it passing `'deployment/*.json'` literally through the loop? (with JSON files inside the `deployment` folder, it works normally)

Interesting to say that I wanted to use `ls deployment | grep .json`, but seems like [this is not recommended](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2010).

Obviously, I can add a check for empty folders before the loop, but I am wondering why my expectation is not the reality here.

Appreciate any explanation.